# Using QUERY and referencing data in other columns/sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the sheet Keywords with columns A-G. Column A is Niche, Column B is Primary Keywords, Column C is Secondary Keyword 1, Column D is Second Keyword 2, Column E is Second Keyword 3, Column F is Second Keyword 4, Column G is Second Keyword 5.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBQAu.png)

I have used FLATTEN in another sheet that provides Second Keyword 1, Second Keyword 2, Second Keyword 3, Second Keyword 4, and Second Keyword 5 from a single row in the Keywords sheet in Column C of the the other sheet, stacking.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6voQM.png)

I would like to have Column A provide the "Niche" and Column B provide the "Primary Keyword" to match with the row they are referenced in the Keywords sheet.

I've attempted to use QUERY formulas but definitely open to suggestions on this as I'm still relatively new to Google Sheets/Excel formulas.

Aiming to have Column A of match the Niche (Column A) of the Keywords sheet based on the Second Keyword provided in Column C.
Also aiming to have Column B match the Primary Keyword (Column B) match the Primary Keyword based on the Second Keyword provided in Column C.
It should appear like so:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuLyN.png)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with something like this that maps through the secondary keywords and joins them with the values of first columns, flattens the values and then splits in three columns. Change "KeySheet" with the actual name of your sheet:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(
LAMBDA(arr,
  FILTER(arr,arr<>""))
 (FLATTEN(MAP(KeySheet!C2:G,LAMBDA(f,IF(f="","",OFFSET(f,0,1-COLUMN(f))&"$"&OFFSET(f,0,2-COLUMN(f))&"$"&f)))))
,"$"))
```

Comment: This is actually perfect to what I was looking to accomplish!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Pivot table example]

I think you're after something like this possibly? If not maybe post a picture with what the desired end result is, because the verbal description is a little hard. You also may need a more unique identifier such as a company name or ID if this is what you're after. Additionally check out this channel if you want a good resource for learning.
[Learn Google/Excel Sheets](https://www.youtube.com/@ExcelGoogleSheets)

Remove this answer if not helpful, or should be a comment.

Comment: Sorry - Added to the original post. Here is what the output should look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuLyN.png